# Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads - NSAttributedStringKey

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting this for the following code in Swift.

```
dictionary.lazy.map { (NSAttributedStringKey($0.key), $0.value)
```

Code is:

```
func convertToAttribute(dictionary: [String: Any]?) -> [NSAttributedStringKey: Any]? {
    guard let dictionary = dictionary else { return nil }

    let convertedAttributes = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
        dictionary.lazy.map { (NSAttributedStringKey($0.key), $0.value) }
    )

    return convertedAttributes
}
```

Can anyone help me to get out of this issue ?

Comment: What version of Xcode/Swift are you using? Your code works on Xcode 9.4 and Swift 4.1.2.

Comment: Yes .. I am using swift 3 ...thanks